# How to schedule the orders Export in BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

How can we schedule the orders to be exported into FTP for every 1 hour in the big commerce? I can export it manually but i need something to run automatically to export the orders data to FTP.Is it possible in BigCommerce?

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 2):

You could write a script to pull orders from the API on an hourly interval (or even better, respond to orders as they come in by using webhooks). If you needed to retrieve the orders from a folder in WebDAV, you could also automate the browser with Selenium to do regular order exports.

Comment: Webhooks really seems like the way to go here.  store/order/created is the one you want: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#order-products-array

Answer (score 0):

At this time you are not able to schedule downloads from the FTP. You can write your own program to do that. We also offer webhooks where you can get order notifications in almost real time. This will also require custom coding and if you need assistance we have a list of [partners](https://www.bigcommerce.com/partners/) who can help out. 
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#webhooks-overview